# Pages render without html, head, and body elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, spree

I'm working on a site using Spree 0.70, Rails 3.1, and Ruby 1.9. I've noticed that some pages are getting rendered without their `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` blocks.

Instead, Rails appears to be automatically wrapping the page in a `<html><body></body></html>` block, which means any code intended to be in the head (i.e. CSS includes, the page `title` block, etc.) shows up inside the body, and anything dependent on attributes of the head or body tags (e.g. CSS) doesn't work because those elements are missing.

This puzzles me because clearly my layout is being rendered, partials and all, but these top-level elements are being ignored or overridden.

When I say "some pages" I've confirmed that it doesn't happen in the admin pages, and it doesn't happen in pages confined to my application (i.e. they don't use the `spree_application.html.erb` layout and their controller doesn't subclass `Spree::BaseController`.) I have overridden the `spree_application.html.erb` layout by making a copy in my application (I had no choice), and all the pages with this problem use that layout. Could that be a factor? ([Here is a page with the broken layout.](http://fs.commonmediainc.com/how-it-works))

How can I get my root elements back?

ETA: Here's the file I have in my app at `app/views/layouts/spree_application.html.erb`. This is the layout which all the pages showing the issue have in common. Note that the div structure is subtly different from the Spree-supplied layout; this is why I need to replace the layout rather than using a Deface override.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<%# Overrides the Spree default template %>
<html>
  <head data-hook="inside_head">
    <%= render 'shared/head' %>
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body class="<%= body_class %>" id="<%= @body_id || 'default' %>" data-hook="body">
    <div id="page-scroll" data-hook>
      <div class='header-wrapper'></div>
      <div id="header" data-hook>
        <ul id="nav-bar" data-hook>
          <%= render 'shared/nav_bar' %>
        </ul>
        <%= render 'shared/logo' %>
      </div>

      <div id="wrapper" data-hook>
        <%= render 'shared/content' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <%= render 'shared/footer' %>
    <%= render 'shared/google_analytics' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any pages in particular? Would you be able to provide some steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Edited the question to include a link to a page with the broken layout.

Comment: Right, but how are you even getting to that stage? I need some steps to reproduce this issue locally before I can even begin to offer a solution.

Comment: I've added a copy of the layout which the sketchy pages have in common. I'm happy to put code up, but it's so unclear to me where in the Spree/Rails stack the problem lies that I'm not sure which code is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by moving the ERb comment out of the `<html>` container and into the `<head>` container. My theory, which I haven't had time to confirm, is that when Deface is in use (which it is, in Spree) even the ERb templates need to be valid, and having anything other than `<head>...</head><body>...</body>` containers inside `<html></html>` is not valid. So either Deface (or Nokogiri, which Deface uses under the hood) is rewriting this to force it to be valid, or it's stripping those containers and Rails is adding the basic code before output.